# how to use Java String property contains/startsWith on fastlane option variable of String Type

Tags: android, yaml, github-actions, cicd, fastlane

Below is my code where I need to check if variable starts with "QA_" or not, Thanks for the appreciation in advance.

```
   desc "CREATE BUILD BY TAG"
   lane :createBuildByTag do |options|
       env = options[:env]
       # if env == "QA_0.0"
       # contains not working for below line
       if options[:env].contains("QA_")
            gradle(task: "clean assemblePreStageDebug")
            upload_drive(options)
       end
   end


   #  Note- I am calling above method by below command
   - name: upload driveStageAPK to Google Drive
     run: bundle exec fastlane createBuildByTag env:"${{ github.ref_name }}"   
     #QA_9.9.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you writing Ruby code in Fastfile or using Java to check the pattern the string matches?

If the former, the function you are looking for is include()

So,

```
...

 if env && env.include?("QA_")
    #rest of code
 ...
```

This first checks that `env` is not `nil` in order to avoid `NoMEthodError`.